# Android Studio, Activity Switching question

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have been trying to create this login/registration app in Android Studio, but I am having an issue. When I go to the Registration Activity I cannot get back to the login Activity by clicking on the TextView I set an OnClickListener for. Also, when I press the sign up button on the Registration Activity, it should take me back to the Login/Main Activity and it doesn't. Below I have the code for both Activites plus the manifests. Could someone tell me where my mistake is?

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.cedricpaige.mercurylogin">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".RegActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText Name;
private EditText Password;
private TextView Info;
private Button Login;
private int counter = 5;
private TextView userReg;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passText);
    Info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    userReg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvReg);
    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    Info.setText("No. of attempts remaining: 5");


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegActivity.class));
    }


    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            validate(Name.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    userReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegActivity.class));
        }
    });

}


private void validate(String userName, String userPassword) {

    progressDialog.setMessage("Signing In!");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userName, userPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                counter--;
                Info.setText("Number of attempts remaining: " + counter);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (counter == 0) {
                    Login.setEnabled(false);
                }

            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

REGISTRATION ACTIVITY

```
public class RegActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText userName, userPassword, userEmail;
private Button regButton;
private TextView userLogin;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg);
    setupUIViews();


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (validate()) {


                String user_email = userEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String pass_word = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email,pass_word).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, "Registration Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(RegActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, "Registration Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        }
                });

            }
        }
    });


    userLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(RegActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });

}
    private void setupUIViews() {

    userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    userPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    userEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    regButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp);
    userLogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewAlready);

    }

    private Boolean validate() {
        Boolean result = false;

        String name = userName.getText().toString();
        String password = userPassword.getText().toString();
        String email = userEmail.getText().toString();

        if (name.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()) {

            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter all details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity, you have this line of code in your onCreate()

```
 if (user != null) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegActivity.class));
    }
```

This is just working like an authListener(), when your Activity starts it will see if the user is != null to enter in that block.

When you use this code in your RegisterActivity

```
 regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (validate()) {


                String user_email = userEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String pass_word = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email,pass_word).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, "Registration Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(RegActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, "Registration Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        }
                });

            }
        }
    });
```

after `if (task.isSuccessful()) {...` you are starting again the MainActivity, which will go to check again inside `onCreate()` if the user is `!= null`.

Since you just registered an user, automatically `getCurrentUser() != null` , so it will enter in that if statment and finish your `MainActivity.class` , and then relaunch your `RegisterActivity.class`

A simple solution will be instead of bringing the user back to the login activity (MainActivity.class), send your user to the Activity after they log in, since now the user is !=null you don't need to request for a login again to the user.

If that is not your use case, just by removing `finish()` from your `MainActivity` will do the job, and instead of doing another intent at your `RegisterActivity`, just do a finish after `task.isSuccefull`

You can place a debug breakpoint at that if statement in your MainActivity to see the changes of the user, and then you can be sure that the user is null or not

**Tip**

I see you use uppercase names for your variables, instead of doing this

```
private Button Login;
```

do this

```
private Button mBtnLogin;
```

It will not change anything at your code, but defining your variables with `CamelCase` will decrease the risk in the future of your app development to confuse it with some method call